# How to start next thread when any one of 5 set of threads is stopped?

Tags: java, multithreading

I am creating program to run a logic in parallel with help of thread. The logic has to be done in a loop of a list and that list may contain 1000 rows to process , so i started each thread in a loop and once thread size reaches 5, i will call thread.join for all the 5 started thread.
So i think that this will start the 2nd set of 5 threads only after the first set of 5 threads are completed? is my understanding correct? i am kind of new to threads.

So my need is to start the 6th thread when any one of the previous set of 5 threads in completed. or start 6th and 7th when any 2 in the previous set of threads are completed.

My code

```
public static void executeTest(){
         for (int i = 0; i < rows1; i++) {
                    RunnableInterface task = new New RunnableInterface(params);
                    Thread thread = new Thread(task);
                    thread.start();
                    threads.add(thread);
                    if ((threads.size() % 5 == 0) || ((i == rows1-1) && (threads.size() < 5))) {
                        waitForThreads(threads);
                    }
                }
}
    private static void waitForThreads(List<Thread> threads) {
            for (Thread thread : threads) {
                try {
                    thread.join();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            threads.clear();
        }
```

What kind of modification do i need to do to achieve above mentioned results

Comment: in the nutshell it is a semaphore problem you don't have to create logic yourself to do it, try to use Sempahore(https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html)  here is an example (https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/semaphore-in-java/)

Comment: Adding to Arpit comment, you can use an `ExecutorService` with a fixed amount of threads: `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);`. You will add as many threads to be executed as you want but the ExecutorService will only execute 5 at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an `ExecutorService` with unbounded input queue and fixed number of threads like this:

```
ExecutorService exec = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
// As many times as needed:
for(int i = 0; i< 100_000; i++) {
    Runnable myrunnable = () -> {}; // new RunnableInterface(params)
    exec.submit(myrunnable);
}
exec.shutdown();
exec.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.DAYS);
```

In JDK19 the executor service is `AutoClosable`, so you can simplify to:

```
try (ExecutorService exec = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5)) {
   ...
}
```

Comment: Got it. Let me try

Comment: @Karthi Apologies - ignore my previous answer with use of queue size, as it fails

Comment: 1. what is this qSize really means? As this ExecutorService is submitting in a loop, the items to be processed will be queued and from queue it will be processed, so by setting the qSize to 1000 means it will block further execution (halts the loops) untill the queue value is less than 1000. Is my understanding correct?
2. So this ExecutorService will always execute 5 threads but we are adding all the items in the loop. So will this have any impact on memory ?

Comment: Once all 5 worker threads are busy additional actions get added to the queue and only processed once each thread is free again. But if you are in situation that you queue vast quantities to this ExecutorService with slow running items, the unprocessed item queue might be a possible cause of OutOfMemoryError. I'll amend this question if I find where I put my fixed size queue example, don't use the example I've deleted.

Comment: Got it.. BTW the answer is working as expected. Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

When in doubt, break it down into smaller, simpler functions:

```java
public static void executeTest(){
    for (int i = 0; i < rows1; i++) {
        startFiveThreads(i);
        awaitFiveThreads(i);
    }
}

private static void startFiveThreads(int i) {
    ...
}

private static void awaitFiveThreads(int i) {
    ...
}
```

But seriously? I'm giving you a literal answer to your *question*—a better way to implement your solution. @DuncG showed you a better solution for your *problem.* Definitely go with what DuncG said, but maybe remember what I said for next time you are trying to implement some tricky/complex algorithm.